# Can't get node-google-spreadsheet to work in Corvid Wix

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, velo

I'm trying to use the `node-google-spreadsheet` package (platform Wix and Corvid), thus:

```
import { GoogleSpreadsheet } from 'google-spreadsheet'; 

function handleSpreadsheet(request) {
    let doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(<spreadsheet ID>); 
    doc.useServiceAccountAuth(<credentials>)
       .then(() => {
           doc.loadInfo();
       })
       .then(() => {
           // Logging Point
           var sheet = doc.sheetsByTitle['May 1'];
       });
```

Up to the Logging Point, things seem to have worked correctly. If I do "console.log(doc)" there it shows that doc has a `_rawSheets` property that has all the correct sheets of my spreadsheet (two dozen or so); each sheet has the correct ID and title and so forth. That is, it has definitely loaded at least that much data from Google Sheets.

But the reference to doc.sheetsByTitle (which is the next step, getting a sheet object) throws an error, and I don't know why. The other sheet access functions, e.g. sheetsById, also throw errors. These are defined as "get" properties in the source, and it's as though Corvid's JS doesn't understand "get".

In desperation I have tried to get at these objects directly, but something that I don't understand is preventing me. Here are some examples of the output of console.log, all taken at the Logging Point above:

```
console.log(doc._rawSheets)       ==> { 0: {...}, 106791250: {...}, ...}
console.log(doc._rawSheets["0"])  ==> null
console.log(doc._rawSheets[0])    ==> null
console.log(Object.keys(doc._rawSheets)) ==> Array(0)
console.log(doc.sheetsByTitle)    ==> null
```

Corvid peculiarity? User PEBKAC? Advice on things to try greatly appreciated.

For the record, the documentation for the node-google-spreadsheet package is [here](https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet/#/).

Comment: Not sure - if I were you, I would use the official client library... Btw, what's the error? Oh, and can you show the rest of your flow - where and how do you try to access the newly loaded properties?

Comment: Also, you really don't want to access the "private" underscored property ( why people insist on sacrificing privacy for the convenience of `class` declaration is beyond me ). Upon rereading your question I think you might have a slight misunderstanding of how async functions work in JS...

Comment: @OlegValter I have massaged the question with more details on what I've done and why. Since I'm writing code for a Wix website, I can use only the packages/libraries they provide (I think); this is one of three available for Google Sheets interface---the others won't work for other reasons, e.g. one is read-only. I would be thrilled, nay ecstatic, to learn of any misunderstanding I have of JS async functions, but I will say that using async/await in place of .then makes no difference to the outcome.

Comment: Massaged? :) Ok, I am unfamiliar with how Wix platform works, but if you have access to installing packages from npm, you should also be able to install the official client library (I just find working with it easier, that's all). If that's not possible, that's of course ok. Thank you for providing info on where you log the `doc` object - without the context it started to look suspiciously like exiting async context. Can you try returning the `doc` object from the first `then` handler and logging it in the second while referring to it as a callback parameter? Just to sanity-check.

Comment: Also: The error information I get from Wix is empty, unfortunately, but I'd say it was probably from an attempt to index off a null object.

Comment: @OlegValter I tried your suggestion and it made no difference, as I'm sure you expect, since doc is declared outside the context. I will try again to get at the official client library, or indeed any other library for Sheets. But in Wix I can get access only to libraries on their "approved" list, which list I have searched diligently. I can also request that they approve other packages and have done so for all Sheets packages I can find.

Comment: ridiculous that they would approve the third-party library and not approve the official one, but you never know... Yes, I expected nothing to change, although it strikes me as odd that data would disappear. The only way it can happen in a Node.js environment is by accidentally exiting async context, which seems not to be the case here. Can you add an `async/await` version here as well? The discussion in comments becomes lengthy, so it would be nice to have a permanent reference.